# Open problems in string theory

Tags: string-theory

I'm thinking of applying to do a PhD in String Theory. I'm gradually learning more about the subject through external reading, but still most papers are impenetrable. Could anyone give me a description of the areas of current String Theory research that would be accessible for a doctoral student? Are there any particular open problems that might be worth getting to know?

Also any general advice on how to choose a PhD topic would be most welcome.

Comment: Your opinion-based question in the last paragraph will likely lead to this question getting closed. If you remove it, the question would have a better chance of staying open (but it would still likely be too broad to be answerable).

Comment: As with *any* topic, there is a PhD thesis for you if and only if there is an adviser willing to take you on as a student in that topic. Open questions are irrelevant if no one in your university will mentor you in them, and questions that aren't famous make perfectly for perfectly good research under the right tutelage.